# Is there any easy, readable way to parse a table Python in a functional way?

Tags: c#, python, linq, list-comprehension

I have the following piece of text:

```
  | job_id | brand | start_date |
  | 1      | zara  | now        |
  | 2      | zara  | now        |
  | 3      | zara  | 2017-1-1   |
  | 4      | zara  | 2017-1-2   |
```

I need to parse this table into an array of dictionaries, with each dictionary being a row indexed by the header. Something like this:

```
[{'job_id':'1', 'brand': 'zara', 'start_date':'now'},
{'job_id':'2', 'brand': 'zara', 'start_date':'now'}...]
```

I'm very fond of functional programming and immutability wherever possible, so I tried doing that in python resulting in the following code:

```
def remove_empty_entries(data):
    return [d for d in data if d]

rows = table.split('\n')
headers = remove_empty_entries([ row.strip() for row in rows[0].split('|') ])
datarow = [remove_empty_entries(map(lambda x: x.strip(), row.split('|')))
        for row in rows[1:]]

result = [ dict(zip(headers, row)) for row in datarow ]
```

This piece of codes makes me think python is overly complicated to process, filter and transform lists or other data structures compared to, say, C# and LINQ. I find list comprehesions harder to read compared to a fluent API like LINQ. I would do something like this:

```
// This will give me the lines already trimmed of any extra space
lines = table.split('\n')
         .Select(line => line.split('|').Select(value => value.Trim()).Where(value => !value.IsNullOrEmpty())).ToList()

header = lines[0]
rowdata = lines.Skip(1).ToList()

rowdata.Select(row => header.Zip(row).ToDictionary(x => x.Item1))
```

I just developed this out of my mind without testing, so I'm not sure if this code even compiles, but I hope I can make my point. I could do some extract methods in the lambdas to increase readability.

Is there any way to achieve greater readability with Python in this specific operation while keeping it functional-style programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are doing too much work. I'd just stick to list comprehensions here:

```
rows = [[col.strip() for col in row.split('|')] for row in table.splitlines()]
headers = [col for col in rows[0] if col]
result = [dict(zip(headers, (c for c in row if c))) for row in rows[1:]]
```

Demo:

```
>>> rows = [[col.strip() for col in row.split('|')] for row in table.splitlines()]
>>> headers = [col for col in rows[0] if col]
>>> result = [dict(zip(headers, (c for c in row if c))) for row in rows[1:]]
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(result)
[{'brand': 'zara', 'job_id': '1', 'start_date': 'now'},
 {'brand': 'zara', 'job_id': '2', 'start_date': 'now'},
 {'brand': 'zara', 'job_id': '3', 'start_date': '2017-1-1'},
 {'brand': 'zara', 'job_id': '4', 'start_date': '2017-1-2'}]
```

For a more generic approach, you could just use the [`asciitable` package](http://cxc.harvard.edu/contrib/asciitable/):

```
>>> import asciitable
>>> asciitable.read(table, Reader=asciitable.FixedWidth, numpy=False, exclude_names=[''])
{'job_id': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'brand': ['zara', 'zara', 'zara', 'zara'], 'start_date': ['now', 'now', '2017-1-1', '2017-1-2']}
>>> pprint(_)
{'brand': ['zara', 'zara', 'zara', 'zara'],
 'job_id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
 'start_date': ['now', 'now', '2017-1-1', '2017-1-2']}
```